# Replicating leafletjs interactive choropleth map example using leaflet package in R

Tags: r, leaflet

I would like to be able to replicate the [Interactive Chroropleth Map example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) from leafletjs using R's `leaflet` package, which has an intro [here](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/)

However, I seem to be struggling even at the first few hurdles...

Below is what I have done so far:

```
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
# Download js file
download.file('http://leafletjs.com/examples/us-states.js',destfile='us-states.js')
# Generate base map (but not sure how to add the js file data)...
m = leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(-96,37.8,zoom=4)
m
```

Comment: There is a choropleth map example made with R and leaflet on this page: http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/map_widget.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in R:

http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/57933_7b3caba2c24e4af686420c9f27437719.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's usually helpful to add the main idea of the page you link to also here, since links may get stale.